# Help with a proof of the computability of the monus function by recursion

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, computability, recursion, computational-mathematics

Reading a text on computability by a guy called Cutland, and he basically asserts the following, which is suppose to be a proof by recursion that *x* ∸ 1 is a computable function:

**(1)** 0 ∸ 1 = 0

**(2)** (*x*+1) ∸ 1 = *x*; by recursion

So my question is: how on earth is this a proof of *x* ∸ 1 being computable? I just don't see how, say, 3 ∸ 1 = 2 can be derived from 0 ∸ 1 = 0? What I mean is, (1) isn't included in the expression on the right hand side of the equation in (2), so in what sense is this a recursive definition?

Comment: $3∸1=(2+1)∸1$; thus, apply the second equation: $(2+1)∸1=2$.

Comment: The definition is a special case of the method (called **Recursion**) of defining a function by specifying each of its values in terms of previously defined values, and possibly using other already defined functions; see (4.1).

Comment: I don't have *Cutland*, but one common clause in the definition of primitive recursion is $f(x+1)=G(f(x),x)$, where $G=G(t,x)$ is primitive recursive. In this case,  $G(t,x)$ is the very simple function $G(t,x)=x$, so does not depend on $t$. But nothing in the definition says that $G$ has to depend on $t$.